# refresh grid in vb.net after deleting any record from access db

Tags: vb.net

i am using access database in which, when i delete any record, it doesn't refresh this gridview it gives error

> 'Access' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

```
Public Sub RefreshGrid()

    ' RUN QUERY
    Access.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Members ORDER BY username ASC")

    ' REPORT & ABORT ON ERRORS
    If NoErrors(True) = False Then Exit Sub

    ' FILL DATAGRID
    dgvData.DataSource = Access.DBDT

    ' CLEAR COMBOBOX
    cbxUsers.Items.Clear()

    ' FILL COMBOBOX
    For Each R As DataRow In Access.DBDT.Rows
        cbxUsers.Items.Add(R("username"))
    Next

    ' DISPLAY FIRS NAME FOUND
    If Access.RecordCount > 0 Then cbxUsers.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Execute `RefreshGrid` again after deleting record from database

Comment: i did it but still problem is there                                                                     'Access' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: Guessing that's your error, because it was not in the picture

Comment: i have put refreshgrid() in delete button ElseIf okToDelete = MsgBoxResult.No Then
        End If
        'RefreshGrid()

    End Sub

Comment: For answering your question we need to see whole your project. Find where `Access` is declared and check it declared in the way that other classes can have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think You are calling Function "RefreshGrid" it has not access of variable "Access", make Access public or re-declare it inside of "RefreshGrid" Function.

Comment: re-declaring will not pass the original object. it needs to be declared globally